# Build OpenCV binding in Haskell for OpenCV 2.4

Tags: opencv, haskell

I tried to install `cv` library via cabal (`cabal install cv`).
But it brings me up an error:

```
Configuring CV-0.3.7...
Building CV-0.3.7...
Preprocessing library CV-0.3.7...
c2hs: C header contains errors:

dist/build/CV/Video.chs.h:22: (column 39) [ERROR]  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U' in the header file.

cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
CV-0.3.7 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have read that it's problem is, that my install `opencv` is newer than the haskell-library needs it.

My `opencv`:

```
local/opencv 2.4.12.2-2
    Open Source Computer Vision Library
```

So how can I fix this error now? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you find and try the potential solution to this precise problem on the [github page](https://github.com/aleator/CV/wiki/BuildProblems) of the `cv` package? There is also [this](https://github.com/aleator/CV/issues/52) issue which appears to indicate this issue has been fixed in recent versions, which don't appear to be on hackage. But even the newest versions seem outdated.

Comment: Yeah i've tried this. But it didn't worked. same error.

Comment: In this case I think this is just a bug with the library. Your choices are to revert to an old version of OpenCV and hope that fixes it, contact the library maintainer and hope they fix it, or try to fix these errors manually, maybe removing some bogus lines in this file will help.

Comment: But I'm not skilled nought to fix it by my own. Could you help please?

Comment: I cannot because I don't even have a machine on which I can install OpenCV to then try to hack on the `cv` package.

Comment: You can try this one: [Haskell binding to OpenCV-3.1](https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv) it works nicely. The problem is it is OpenCV3.1. You can check an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505855/calling-a-c-opencv-function-from-haskell/39515797#39515797