# Calling a C opencv function from haskell

Tags: c++, c, opencv, haskell

I'm trying to use OpenCV with Haskell. My idea is calling the c++ function from Haskell.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Lib
    (
        someFunc
    ) where

import Foreign.C
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Ptr

data LplROI = LplROI {
    coi :: CInt,
    xOffset :: CInt,
    yOffset :: CInt
}

data LpImage = LpImage {
    align :: CInt,
    alphaChannel :: CInt,
    borderConst :: CInt,
    borderMode :: CInt,
    channelSeq :: CChar,
    colorModel :: CChar,
    dataOrder :: CInt,
    depth :: CInt,
    height :: CInt,
    id :: CInt,
    imageData :: CChar, 
    mageDataOrigin :: CChar,
    imageId :: CChar,
    imageSize :: CInt,
    maskROI :: LpImage,
    nChannels :: CInt, 
    nSize :: CInt,
    origin :: CInt,
    roi :: LplROI,
    tileInfo :: CChar,
    width :: CInt,
    widthStep :: CInt
}

foreign import ccall "_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi" imRead_ImRead :: CString -> CInt -> IO (Ptr LpImage)

someFunc = do
    filename <- newCString "/home/chuck/Pictures/such-a-bad-day.jpg"
    imRead_ImRead filename 1
```

I read this post [CPlusPlus from Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/CPlusPlus_from_Haskell), and so I got the name *_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi*. In *2.1.1 Finding the mangled named*.

But GHCi says:

> ByteCodeLink: can't find label
>   During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol:
>     _ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi

In Python I should "import cv2", but I don't know how it works on Haskell.

I also read: [FFI cook book](https://wiki.haskell.org/FFI_cook_book) But I can't get an answer to my question there.

Any idea?

Comment: How do you tell GHCi which libraries to search for this symbol?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know. I don't see here: [CPlusPlus from Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/CPlusPlus_from_Haskell) where he does it. I thought maybe in the cabal file. Something like this: `library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib  
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  default-language:    Haskell2010` 
With a ghci option, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you have a cabal file, try `cabal repl` instead of `ghci`. Cabal ought to tell ghci which libs to use.

Comment: I tried `cabal repl` and `stack repl`, but I'm still getting the same error. Where should I specify the libs? @n.m.

Comment: Can you build a standalone executable with Cabal or stack?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what do you exactly mean with standalone. I've built it with stack, if that's your question. The folder contains a cabal file, a Setup.hs, the stack yaml, and the src.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123431/discussion-between-n-m-and-chuck-aguilar).

Comment: Your program would not work anyways, since OpenCV's `String` type is not a C string.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to use existing OpenCV bindings like https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv.

Comment: Yep, it works, thank you! It's a nice Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was trying doesn't work. 
The OpenCV api is written in C++. That's why the way to call it is here: [C++ from haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/CPlusPlus_from_Haskell). But when you install OpenCV in "/usr/lib/", you don't get a .so file like *cv2.so*. It means that's quite difficult to use `foreign import ccall` as the c-name is not built. 
So, I used what @ReidBarton said "[haskell-opencv](https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv)" and it works nicely. Or at least easier than the other way.

Here is a use example:

```
module Lib
( someFunc
) where

import Control.Monad ( void )
import qualified OpenCV as CV
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = do
    img <- CV.imdecode CV.ImreadUnchanged <$> B.readFile "/some_pic.jpg"
    CV.withWindow "test" $ \window -> do
     CV.imshow window img
     void $ CV.waitKey 10000
```

in the `stack.yaml` I added this:

```
packages:    
 - location:
    git: https://github.com/LumiGuide/haskell-opencv.git
    commit: 07afde39fa16f7a4282d4a812e70b9ed33d0f3ef
 - '.'
```

and so looks a part of the cabal file:

```
library  
 hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , opencv
                     , bytestring
  default-language:    Haskell2010

 executable simple-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
 -- ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , simple
                     , opencv
                     , bytestring
  default-language:    Haskell2010

 test-suite simple-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , simple
                     , opencv
                     , bytestring
 -- ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: `haskell-opencv` isn't avaiable via hackage, is it?